# Test a call to a passed callback in a directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

Im trying to test the logic of calling the callback, passed as parameters to directive.

My directive is initiated as this:

```
 var directive = {
        ...
        scope: {
            onSave: '&'
        },
        controller: 'TmpViewCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true // Isolate scope
    };
```

In the Controller i using storing this as vm variable ( John Pappas styleguide)

```
function TmpViewCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.save = save;
    function save(element) {
        if (element !== undefined) {
            vm.onSave({element: element});
        }
    }
```

In my test im using following beforeEach:

```
 var dataMock = {
    onSave: function (elem) {
        return true;
    },
beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_('TmpViewCtrl', {$scope: $rootScope}, dataMock);
    // Compile a piece of HTML containing the directive
    element = $compile("<div tmp-view ></div>")($rootScope);
    // fire all the watches, so the scope expressions will be evaluated
    $rootScope.$digest();

}));
```

My Test looks like

```
it('If save is triggered, callback should be called', function () {
    // Check that the compiled element contains the templated content
    var temp = {test: "test"};
    spyOn($rootScope, "save");
    spyOn($controller, "onSave");
    $rootScope.save(temp);
    expect($rootScope.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($controller.onSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Well the controller has the last line says that 
`Expected spy onSave to have been called.`, but it should be called? Or i am checking false controller scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came here looking for a way to mock callbacks passed to angular 2 components. Found the answer in the page suggested by @silbermm. Basically `jasmin.createSpy` is what does the trick.

```
$rootScope.save = jasmin.createSpy("save");
$controller.onSave = jasmin.createSpy("onSave");
expect($rootScope.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect($controller.onSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to do the same thing. I stumbled across an article describing how to do it - http://busypeoples.github.io/post/testing-components-angular-js/.